# Spring Boot как добавить соединение с БД в контекст приложения

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rethinkdb

Есть приложение на спринг буте. Я хочу написать класс, который будет делать реконнект к `RethinkDB`, если база упала. Я запустил таск, который проверяет, живо ли соединение, и если оно закрыто, то надо создать новое подключение и добавить его в контекст приложения. Класс такой:

```
package service;

import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Connection;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class RethinkDBReconnector {

    @Autowired
    private RethinkDB r;

    @Autowired
    private Connection conn;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void task() {
        if (!conn.isOpen()) {
            System.out.println("closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Соединение сконфигурировано так:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public Connection connection(RethinkDB r) {
        return r.connection().hostname("127.0.0.1").port(28015).connect();
    }

    @Bean
    public RethinkDB rethinkDB() {
        return RethinkDB.r;
    }
}
```

Но я не знаю, как получить контекст приложения и добавить в него новое соединение так, чтобы его можно было использовать вместо старого. Не знаю, можно ли его внедрить как зависимость. Скорее всего нет. Как можно решить эту задачу?

Проблема не решена. Присваивание нового значения ссылке в реконнекторе не обновляет соединение глобально.

Попытался сделать так:

```
@Bean
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public Connection connection(RethinkDB r) {
    Connection conn = r.connection().connect();
    if (conn == null || (!conn.isOpen())) {
        conn = r.connection().connect();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

При запуске возникает исключение:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'connection': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$null$1(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:359)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$2(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: А зачем его заново добавлять? Я так понял, что ссылка на объект Connection, который  уже использует контекст уже получена при помощи @Autowired. Если вам нужно создавать новое соединение, то создавайте его и присваиваете переменной conn. Контекст будет ссылаться на неё.

Comment: @Xoxole, спасибо. Соединение пересоздается, но при записи в базу возникает ошибка `Can't write query because response pump is not running.` Как исправить?

Comment: Повестьте ваш `@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)` на метод создания коннекта(с проверкой на `null` и на `!conn.isOpen()`)

Comment: @Xoxole, нет, не работает. Соединение не обновляется для всего приложения.

Comment: @Chubatiy, в каком классе? В классе конфигурации бинов?

Comment: Да. Поидее контекст будет подтягивать новый коннект. Попробуйте

Comment: @Chubatiy, нет, у меня так не работает. Пример кода добавил в пост.

Comment: Добавил ответ, что я имел ввиду))

Comment: @typemoon может у вас в других местах приложения используется другой экземпляр класса Connection, не тот который в контексте?

Answer (score 0):

В классе SpringConfig

```
.....    
@Autowired
private Connection conn;

@Bean
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public Connection connection() {
    if (null != conn && conn.isOpen()) {
        return conn;
    }
    return RethinkDB.r.connection().hostname("127.0.0.1").port(28015).connect();
}
.....
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает Error creating bean with name 'rethinkDB': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Comment: немного исправил. Попробуйте ещё раз(убрал поле)

Comment: я тоже убирал поля. Все равно не работает, даже если разнести начальную конфигурацию коннекта и код реинициализации в разные файлы конфигов.